# Confidence region for multinomial distribution with k=7 - including 5 zero values in dataset

Tags: distributions, inference, sas, multinomial-distribution, sparse

I have a multinomial distribution with $k=7$ and an observed dataset $n_i = \{62, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0\}$.

While it was quite expected that $n_i = 0$ for $i \in \{3,4,...,7\}$, there was no way to exclude these outcomes ex ante since they are an integral part of the "game".

**My goal** is very straightforward: I basically like to show, that outcomes $1$ and $2$ are more likely than each of the other outcomes and currently plan to simultaneously calculate the confidence region for all $\pi_i$.

I found **various approaches**, see for example [SAS-Blog: Confidence Intervals for Multinomial Parameters](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/15/confidence-intervals-multinomial-proportions.html) or [StackExchange: Sison & Glaz for multinomial parameters for small samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/simultaneous-confidence-intervals-for-multinomial-parameters-for-small-samples/20589#20589). While the former usually requires cell counts $\geq 5$, the latter (Sison & Glaz) seems to perform well with sparse datasets. However, [May and Johnson conclude that](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/William_Johnson9/publication/5142788_Constructing_Two-Sided_Simultaneous_Confidence_Intervals_for_Multinomial_Proportions_for_Small_Counts_in_a_Large_Number_of_Cells/links/0deec52a60bb3cdf50000000.pdf) *"If some cell counts dominate, the Sison and Glaz intervals do not perform well."*

**Questions:**

- Would you recommend using Sison & Glaz anyway?
- I guess I could solve this issue using bootstrapping procedures - however, is there really a need for it or should I use a completely different approach (categorizing outcomes and use binomial confidence intervals,...)?

Any help would be appreciated!